# dynamically adding a template and binding data

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have a ScrollViewer and wish to add a image, some text and then multiple template items. How  can i add a template item that i have stored in `<Application.Resources>` and bind data to it?

Something like(the code is meant to be informative only) :

```
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    sp.AddTemplate("TemplateNameFromResources");
    sp.BindToData(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx
 in this link there is a code by name globalization they have used resource file and bound it to list box or something check out it might help